# LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid ui lagging

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-glide

I'm trying to load images from ROOM (images stored as Bitmap) and i'm using paging 3
but the ui is lagging, I tried using Glide but it didn't fix the issue, i think the issue is related to the size of the images.

this is my code

````
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(top = 10.dp),
        columns = StaggeredGridCells.Fixed(2),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(10.dp),
        verticalItemSpacing = 10.dp,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp)
    ) {
        items(arti.itemCount) { item ->
            arti[item]?.let { artifact ->
                artifact.bitmap.let { bitmap ->
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                    ) {
                        GlideImage(
                            model = bitmap,
                            contentDescription = "",
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .aspectRatio(bitmap.width.toFloat() / bitmap.height.toFloat())
                                .clip(MaterialTheme.shapes.small)
                                .clickable {
                                    navController.navigate(RootGraph.FULLSCREEN + "/${artifact.seed}") {
                                        launchSingleTop = true
                                    }
                                }
                        )
                    }
                }

            }
    enter code here
        }```
````